# hook_update_n($sandbox) batch getting executed only once

Tags: 8, batch-operations

Following is the code where I'm willing to update the `description` of the `field_meta_tags` of all my products using the batch process.

It's getting executed & working as expected, but only for the first batch.

```
function mymodule_update_8001($sandbox) {
  if (!isset($sandbox['total'])) {
    $products = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product')
      ->condition('type', 'default')
      ->execute();
    $sandbox['total'] = count($products);
    $sandbox['current'] = 0;
  }

  $products_per_batch = 25;

  $products = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product')
    ->condition('type', 'default')
    ->range($sandbox['current'], $sandbox['current'] + $products_per_batch)
    ->execute();

  foreach ($products as $product_id) {
    $product = Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::load($product_id);
    $product->set('field_meta_tags', serialize(['description' => '']));
    $product->save();
    $sandbox['current']++;
  }

  \Drupal::messenger()
    ->addMessage($sandbox['current'] . ' products processed.');

  $sandbox['#finished'] = empty($sandbox['total']) ? 1 : ($sandbox['current'] / $sandbox['total']);
}
```

Once the above `hook_update_n($sandbox)` is executed, getting the following output at the terminal:

```sh
 --------------- ----------- --------------- ------------- 
  Module          Update ID   Type            Description  
 --------------- ----------- --------------- ------------- 
  mymodule        8001        hook_update_n   Updates.     
 --------------- ----------- --------------- ------------- 

 // Do you wish to run the specified pending updates?: yes.                                                             

>  [notice] Update started: mymodule_update_8001
>  [notice] Update completed: mymodule_update_8001
>  [notice] Message: 25 products processed.
> 
 [success] Finished performing updates.
```

Not sure how `$sandbox['#finished']` is getting the value as 1, since that's how I remember we ask the batch to stop processing.

Comment: "Not sure how $sandbox['#finished'] is getting the value as 1, since that's how I remember we ask the batch to stop processing." hook_update_N() is only run a single time. You seem to be mixing up batch processing and hook_update_N(). Nothing will tell hook_update_N() to run multiple times, it's only ever supposed to run a single time.

Comment: @Jaypan `hook_update_N` implementations can act as batch callbacks (and thus invoked multiple times in the same update script). There's a note on it in [the docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.8.x#sec_bulk)

Comment: No kidding. I stand corrected. Thanks for the link Clive!

Comment: The declaration should be `function mymodule_update_8001(&$sandbox)`, as arrays have [weird pass by value/reference rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030906/are-arrays-in-php-copied-as-value-or-as-reference-to-new-variables-and-when-pas) in PHP.  So, I highly suspect in the UpdateManager(?), this isn't actually being called as a batch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for batches if you intend to run all entries in one process.

This is something we had use to update around 30.000 entries i quickly adapted from your example :

```
/**
 * Query all commerce_product of type default
 *
 * *
 * @param array $sandbox
 *
 * @return string
 *  Number of updated rows
 */
function mymodule_post_update_0801(array $sandbox) {
  /** @var $connection Drupal\Core\Database\Connection */
  $connection = \Drupal::service('database');
  $query = $connection->select('commerce_product', 'p');
  $query->fields('p', ['id'])
    ->condition('type', 'default');
  $toUpdate = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

  $result = array_map( 'update_description_value', $toUpdate);

  return sprintf('Number of row updated: %s', count($result));
}

/**
 * Update a product description
 *
 * @param stdClass $defaultProduct
 *  ->id
 *
 * @return string
 *  product id
 */
function update_description_value($productQueried) {
  /** @var $connection Drupal\Core\Database\Connection */
  $connection = \Drupal::service('database');

  $updated = $connection->update('commerce_product')
    ->fields(['field_meta_tags' => serialize(['description' => ''])])
    ->condition('id', $productQueried->id, '=')
    ->execute();

  return $productQueried->id;
}
```

Let me know if there is typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `drush updb` command will not continue the batch if the update hook does not return a message.

changes required:

- Add `return t("Updated @progress/@max products.", ['@progress' => $sandbox['current'], '@max' => $sandbox['total']]);`
- in function declaration pass $sandbox parameter by reference

changes optional:

- remove messenger()->addMessage() as progress is displayed with the return value. It is not good to use messages in update hooks, as messages will be displayed after the hook is finished (not during execution).
- fix range() second parameter as `->range($sandbox['current'], $products_per_batch)` The range parameters are not from-to, but start-length.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a custom Drush command? If your module is custom, then maybe you don't need to execute the update in `hook_update_HOOK`. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drush9_batch_processing